# Forcing proxy settings per user on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10

How can I force proxy settings per user using Group Policy (or some other method)? I am running Windows 10 Pro (no domain). In the past, it was configured using the Internet Explorer settings using Group Policy and then removing the Connection Settings tab from IE using Group Policy so users couldn't change it. However, with Windows 10, users can configure proxy settings outside of IE (under system settings or by typing proxy into the search bar) so removing the tab from IE is useless.

How can I prevent users from changing proxy settings? Note that I need the configuration to be per user and not system wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the following policy item:

User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer => **Prevent changing proxy settings**

The Settings items will switch to a read-only mode.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!